# How did Ben Richards Know Sub Zero's name in The Running Man

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-running-man

How did [Ben Richards](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0011757/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) know [Subzero](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0849048/?ref_=tt_cl_t9)'s name in [The Running Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093894/)

> Hey Killian, here is subzero, now, plain zero.

I can't imagine they had TV in prison, and he never had the chance to watch an episode of the show, although, Richard's character did know of Killian.

Comment: Isn't he introduced at the beginning of the show? Long time since I've seen it. Even if there isn't, I'd just expect some behind the scenes staff member talking about him or something similar. Or is there even some label on his costume?

Answer (score 2):

The show was on-air before Richard's story line so there is a chance he already knew of the stalkers.

But, as you can hear in [this sound-byte](http://www.hark.com/clips/fkznrhvlkk-sub-zero-introduction), SubZero is introduced in detail so Richards could have simply heard/seen it then.

Related:
In [the book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_%28novel%29), Richards willingly goes to the network which is where he learns about everything (including the stalkers) beforehand.

> After rigorous physical and mental testing, Richards is selected to
>   appear on The Running Man, the Games Network's most popular,
>   lucrative, and dangerous program. He meets with Dan Killian, the
>   executive producer of the program, who describes the challenges he
>   will face once the game begins.